# Bind dynamic DNS: can records be removed or expired automatically after some time

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dynamic-dns

I have a dynamic DNS zone on my Bind 9 server and use `nsupdate` from a script to update records in it.

When a record has not been updated for some time, I would like to remove it.

Do I need to manage this myself in some custom script by keeping track of when records were added and remove them when they are too old?

Or is there some way to tell Bind to automatically remove records after some defined time?

Answer (score 1):

BIND itself doesn't provide a built-in mechanism to automatically remove records after a certain time. You would typically need to manage this yourself through custom scripts or external tools.

One common approach is to implement a cleanup script that periodically checks the last update timestamp for each record and removes those that haven't been updated for a specified duration. You can schedule this script to run at regular intervals using a cron job.

The concept of the "last update timestamp" refers to the time when a DNS record was last modified or updated. In the context of dynamic DNS with BIND and nsupdate, you can create a mechanism to store the timestamp associated with each DNS record. This timestamp is then used to track when a record was last updated.When you add or update a DNS record using nsupdate, include an additional field to store the timestamp. For example, you might add a TXT record that includes the timestamp information.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this part: "the last update timestamp for each record"

Comment: What is your question about it, because to me it's quite clear. Why don't you understand it?

Comment: My question is how one would get at such a thing in a normal BIND9 environment.

Comment: The concept of the "last update timestamp" refers to the time when a DNS record was last modified or updated. In the context of dynamic DNS with BIND and nsupdate, you can create a mechanism to store the timestamp associated with each DNS record. This timestamp is then used to track when a record was last updated.When you add or update a DNS record using nsupdate, include an additional field to store the timestamp. For example, you might add a TXT record that includes the timestamp information.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of elaboration that would make the answer much more useful to the reader, I would suggest adding something like that explanation into the answer proper.

Comment: Done added it as you proposed